# How to build a DFS tree if i generate frequent pattern in a DFS method?

Tags: c++, algorithm, design-patterns, depth-first-search

In my algorithm, i will create frequent pattern by DFS method, for example, i generate `A-A`, `A-A-B`, `A-A-B-C`, ... in order.(These three patterns are frequent subgraph patterns, `A`, `B`, `C` are nodes, and `-` means there exist an edge between two nodes.)
If there does not exist any frequent subgraph consist of `A-A`, we start to generate `A-B`, `A-B-B`, ....
I want to use a DFS tree to store these frequent patterns. But i don't know what is the best method.

The problem i encounter is should i use a *prev pointer to record the pattern in previous level?

```
// When i generate one frequent pattern, i will call `report` 
void report (Projected &projected, unsigned int sup)
{
    // i want to store this pattern in a DFS tree which implement with GPattern
}

struct GPattern {
    CODE code;
    Project project;
    vector<GPattern> children; // record all children of this pattern

    // should i use a `prev` pointer to record ancestor?
};
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you should use a prefix tree. take a look [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trie)

Comment: The frequent patterns i generate is in a DFS order. I have to store each pattern when it generate, but i don't know how to implement it...

Answer (score 0):

You're building a graph of `GPattern` objects, manually. You're probably better off using `Boost::Graph` for that, as it comes with a lot of useful algorithms.

Comment: Thanks for your advisement, but i don't have enough time to change my code and get familiar with Boost...

Comment: Can you help me by solving this question? Thank you:)

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9780955/unexpected-result-of-my-dfs-tree-c